# Python + Selenium -- unable to click button (onClick=openWIndow)

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

**I am trying to click on a button using Python Selenium WebDriver (Chrome).
The HTML of the button:**

```
<button type="button" class="button blue" onclick="openWIndow(LINK_HERE, 'idpage6')">Like</button>
```

*(I had to remove "LINK_HERE", as StackOverflow doesn't allow Google url shorteners)*
Now, I am not a noob, I know how you click on a button. The issue is, the button doesn't respond when I `.click()` on it. The `onClick` field seems to be the root of this problem.

I have tried a lot of different solution, here is two of them:

```
css_selector = 'div.container > div > button'
# Attempt 1
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector )
# Attempt 2
js_script = ''.join(["var elem = document.querySelector('",
                     css_selector,
                     "');",
                     "if( document.createEvent) {",
                     "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');",
                     "evObj.initEvent( 'mouseover', true, false );",
                     "elem.dispatchEvent(evObj);",
                     "} else if( document.createEventObject ) {",
                     "elem.fireEvent('onmouseover');",
                     "}"])

browser.execute_script(js_script)
```

Please note that the button didn't respond, no error was raised at any of the attempts.

Here is a picture to illustrate, what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

**Try it for yourself, you are free to log into my account, I have already written the username and password in the script.** You would have to change the path to the WebDriver though.
Code --> https://pastebin.com/fkYZxywf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the list of elements for your case and get a particular element by index in the list.

```
list_of_like_buttons = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".button.blue")))

# Click on the second "Like"-button.
list_of_like_buttons[1].click()
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I am speechless. I have tried so many different approches, see the two approaches^^ as example. Why don't they work, but yours work? They successfully locate the exact same element?

Comment: @Bjango, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: @Bjango, there is should be a wait before clicking on the "Like"-button.